# Like button likes Facebook Auto Created Page rather than my Own Facebook Fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have an Official Facebook page I've setup for my new company.

I have a like button on my website with the appropriate meta tags related to that website.

But when Someone clicks the "like" button, it "likes" a page on facebook that facebook has automatically created thats not related to my own Facebook Fan Page using the META tags into from my webpage. I am using the iframe code for the like button.

How can I stop this happening? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

On the site you have chosen the Style of your "like" Button you have to put in the Url of your company Facebook page again, if you don't do this you'll get a like-Button for a Facebook page.

Comment: <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;appId=myAppId" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true">

Comment: The part "mydomain.com" irretates me. Look at mine:
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2F**www.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FBlitzer-Warner%2F252764181442255&amp**;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;height=62&amp;appId=228613370503297" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:62px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>

Comment: I don't want to "like" the facebook page, I want to  "like" the website, in this case my website is "mydomain.com

Comment: any success? same issue here: http://thenutritionshop.de a like on on the the products create automatically a like page e.g. https://www.facebook.com/pages/Clif-Bar-Chocolate-Chip-The-Nutrition-Shop-der-Experte-für-Sportnahrung/281414468613490

has to be caused by some meta tag, but i am not sure which